# Laravel: Interface 'Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing this error when trying to call a function that connects to an api.

The full error is:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Interface 'Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface' not found in /path/to/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Uri.php:13
```

Cannot find much help on forums.

**EDIT**

Actually this is all the error I get, see this screenshot:

[image]

Even in the logs that are generated in /storage/logs, I only get this message:

```
[2017-06-08 03:03:35] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Interface 'Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface' not found in /path/to/project/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Uri.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

Comment: The error message is lacking a stack trace, there is not enough information to debug this, and there's nothing in this question to warrant the [laravel] tag.

Comment: My guess is you're using the guzzle client incorrectly, but no way to know given your code. @sisve nailed it.

Comment: Please see my edited post. Actually this is all the error I get in the log. That is why I am stuck myself. @ohgodwhy can you please explain what you mean by using guzzle client incorrectly? Do you mean some version conflict or something else?

Comment: Is your composer version up to date? Have you tried `composer dump-autoload -o`? What version of Guzzle are you using? Guzzle itself is a pretty robust library. Perhaps if you post the code that causes this error, someone might be able to spot a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @fubar, using `composer dump-autoload -o` actually fixed the issue and It worked! Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Nice one. Glad you're sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your composer version up to date? Have you tried `composer dump-autoload -o`?

Comment: This actually fixed the issue. Thanks