# PHP Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface' not found | Laravel 5.6.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem today I ran the "composer update" command in a project and it gave me this error in the error_log:

> Interface 'Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface' not found in /home/simbiothink/simbiothink/config/vendor/psr/http-message/src/ServerRequestInterface.php on line 43

I'm trying to run also:" composer dump-autolad "but I'm not successful. I hope you can help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426116/laravel-interface-psr-http-message-uriinterface-not-found look like similar

Comment: I've dealt with this post before, but I think it has to do with something else from composer.

Comment: try delete the vendor folder then re-install